# Single quoting a command argument with PHP exec()

Tags: php

The following php code snippet used to work before upgrading to php 7.4.x (can't remember what minor php version broke the working code though):

```
       $pw_scheme = (str_replace("$2y$","{BLF-CRYPT}$2y$","$pw_returned->password"));
       exec("/usr/local/bin/doveadm pw -t '$pw_scheme' -p {$_POST['pass']}", $returned_pw, $status);
```

$pw_scheme is correctly set beforehand with a mysqli_fetch_object() request and contains the expected result from str_replace() (checked with print()) but is actually empty when exec() is executed.

I'm kinda lost on where I can fix this...

Comment: It's certainly [brave](https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/php-security-2/) to pass user input directly into `exec`. Try print out the line you pass into `exec` and see if it works directly on the command line, for a starting point.

Comment: @Markus AO Thanks for the link and looking into this! User's input is checked beforehand (it must be an email address only and exists on the mysql database) and access to this web server is only done via a VPN by family members. But you're right about warning how dangerous calls to exec() is.<br /><br />I did some tests with escapshellcmd() and escapeshellargs() as you're link advises to harden the exec() but I couldn't make it works.  ($pw_scheme needs to be supplied with singles quotes to doveadm shell command).  Printing out the line does show the correct shell command to run by exec().